# Inspection Settings for Refactoring to Java 8 in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java-8

In IntelliJ I am able to set inspections for Refactoring to Java 8.

Is there a way to do the same for eclipse ?
I was this in this article, but In my brand new eclipse I can't see howto activate this ?

https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/03/25/eclipse-support-for-java-8/

any help ?

Comment: The blog says 'Quick Fix' so it is 'Edit > Quick Fix'

Comment: Yes this I know ctrl-1, but there are no inspections marked. So when having a loop over a Collection eclipse doesn't suggest me to use Collection.foreach in yellow color. My Question is how to activate that ?